# How to set up a constant background TCP Connection for Android used by multiple activities?

Tags: android, tcp, server, tcpclient

**Context**

Me and a friend are currently building an app which needs to send and retrieve data from a server:

- My friend has the server side taken care of, but I'm not sure how to have a TCP connection that can span multiple activities.
- For the app, the connection has to be started in one activity, data sent in another, data retrieved from the server in a third activity, and the connection finally closed in a fourth activity.
- We plan for the app to require a connection to the server to function. To do this I plan for a boolean to be switched to false when the server connection is lost. That boolean will trigger a safety in the app on any button click.
- Because of that, and the fact that almost every Activity (20 or more) requires data to be sent/received to/from the server, me and my friend want to avoid starting and stopping the connection to avoid strain on the server.

I'm also fairly new to coding, so code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A `Service`?  Did you research at all first?

Comment: @LukePark

 I did read that when I first started my programming, and I just re-read it for good measure, but I don't understand it well. On the surface it seems close to what I need - especially the 'IntentService', but I have some questions:   - How can I prevent it from calling 'stopSelf()'? I need the TCP connection to constantly run in the background as long as the user has the app open in the foreground.   - Since the service runs in the background, how do I kill it when the user leaves the app without an 'onClick' that can send the 'stopSelf()' command?

Comment: @LukePark - How can I have the service handle different requests? If it starts the server connection in on create, I need it to be able to either upload a variable string, download a string, or to close the connection and the service? Also, sorry about formatting, I can't say I understand how to get it to work.

Comment: It sounds like you are a bit in over your head.  If I was you, I would learn more about Android Programming in general first.  Things like Activity life cycle, and about Static Members.  Your questions are a bit too broad.

Comment: @LukePark I have read up on Activity lifecycles, though not about Static Members. But I haven't had any luck with trying to learn from the android website. I find it far too dense because I don't know much about android or programming. Any progress I've made has come from taking working code and playing with it, seeing what I can add/remove/change. It's kinda akin to having read a Dictionary of another language, but not having any knowledge of the grammar.

Comment: That's why I think you should learn more about programming in general first.